# app:preDexDebug error in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, jar, gradle, htmlunit

I am using Android Studio 1.0.1 and Gradle 1.1.0. The following are my gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.17'
}
```

Also, after seeing many answers on SO, I added the following too:

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}
```

I do not have any `jar` in the `libs` folder. I am getting the following error when I `Run` my application:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Since the entire `Gradle Build Message` is large, I am [pasting it here](http://pastebin.com/hpmbEeai).
I do not get the error when I remove the `htmlunit` dependency. From what I can gather, there seem to be some conflicting entities between `htmlunit` and some in-built Android libraries.

I have tried the solutions provided in other such questions, but none is working.

Comment: Try to comment this line :  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) and check is resolve ur problem or not.

Comment: Tried it just now. Still the same error. In any case, the "libs" folder is empty, so it shouldn't have made any difference.

Comment: Try to run this `./gradlew clean assembleDebug --debug` from the project's directory.

Comment: post the full gradle log, extended error message should be there.

Comment: @metalurgus It says the same thing there. I have pasted the log in my question.

Comment: @VladimirS How do I do that? I am on Windows.

Comment: What org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient version used by default in Android? It is indirectly used by HtmlUnit.